# Discord Bot won't delete messages(Eclipse IDE Java with JDA API)

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I tried making a purge command where it deletes the amount of messages a user wants in a discord channel. However, it didn't work out.

```java
public void onGuildReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        Message objMsg = event.getMessage();
        String[] args = objMsg.getContentRaw().split("");
        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Ref.prefix + "purge")) {
            if(args.length <= 2) {
                //TODO
            }else {
                event.getMessage().delete().queue();
                TextChannel target = event.getMessage().getMentionedChannels().get(0);
                purgeMessages(target, Integer.parseInt(args[2]));
            }
        }
    }
    private void purgeMessages(TextChannel channel, int numberofMessages) {
        MessageHistory history = new MessageHistory(channel);
        List<Message> msgs;

        msgs = history.retrievePast(numberofMessages).complete();
        channel.deleteMessages(msgs).queue();

    }
```

I expected the bot to delete the amount of messages specified. However, it has no response. I've used this method of if statements for other commands such as checking your ping so it would most likely be something with the deleting messages.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `split(" ")` rather than `split("")`?

Comment: The method should probably override `onGuildMessageReceived` from `ListenerAdapter`. Your method name seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`channel.deleteMessages(msgs).queue();`, as stated on JDA documentation, "Bulk deletes a list of messages. This is not the same as calling Message.delete() in a loop."
One thing that JDA docs doesn't mention about this, is that discord limits bulk delete only to messages that are less than 2 weeks old. So to delete older messages you'll have to delete them one by one. This was a limitation imposed a few months ago.

The other possible problems that I know of are stated in the docs, the most common being not complying with these:

- "Must be at least 2 messages and not be more than 100 messages at a time. If you only have 1 message, use the Message.delete() method instead."
- "You must have the Permission MESSAGE_MANAGE in this channel to use this function."